# Help translating "There is no god above an awakened man"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Looking for a suitable latin translation for the phrase "There is no god above an awakened man" among latin quotes and text examples, I came up with these -obviously imperfect- phrases.

> Non deus est super hominem illuminantem
>
> Non deus est super hominem cogitantem

My main problem resides on finding a word for *awakened* in the same connotation of the phrase (more in the **enlightened** sense than the "waking up from a dream" sense).

The word *god* should be also more a generic term (like deity), not the name of certain exclusive god, so I don't know if *deus* is correctly used.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You explain your question nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Draconis, I opt for a construction with *nullus deus*.

However, I don't agree with either him or Hugh on the verb: when *praesum* does **vaguely** mean "standing above" (it can be considered its literal translation, *prae*+*sum*), it really has the specific meaning of **presiding** over, or commanding, something - it can have other nuances, but these don't include that of being morally or socially superior to someone else. Instead, I would go for *antecedo,-is,-cessi,-cessum,-ĕre*.

In his *Moral letters to Lucilius*, Liber VIII, Seneca the Younger wrote:

> Iuppiter quo antecedit virum bonum?
>
> "In what is Jupiter superior to a virtuous man?"

To conclude, *suscitatus,-a (,-um)* was more often than not used with the meaning of "resurrected". At best, it is ambiguous.

It seems to me there is no exact analogue of "awakened", and *illuminatus* for "enlightened" was only used to describe elegant speech, prose or poetry. Within Church Latin, *illuminatus* assumes a connotation similar to *enlightened*, however its religious trait makes it uneffective for the message of your sentence.

I think Cicero gives us a great option (my highlighting):

> [...] hoc primum intellegamus, hominum duo esse genera, alterum indoctum et agreste, quod anteferat semper utilitatem honestati, alterum **humanum** et politum, quod rebus omnibus dignitatem anteponat.
>
> "[...] we first consider this, the fact that there are two kinds of men: one ignorant and rude, who prefers profit over integrity; the other, **virtuous** and  refined, who places dignity above everything."

**Wrapping things up**, my translation is:

*Nullus deus antecedit hominem humanum.*

In other words, Man needs nothing but the wisdom to pursue what he can find in himself, to reach godlike virtue.

Note: I translated both *bonum* and *humanum* as "virtuous", but they clearly have different connotations. Plus, the juxtaposition *hominem humanum* better serves the purpose I explained above.

Comment: Thanks, I like a lot your examples and I think you got the message that the phrase tries to convey. And the use of the word humanum is quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Hugh's use of *Dīs*: instead I would use *deus*, a nice, standard word for "god" commonly used for the entire Roman pantheon. *Praesum* is a good word for "stand above", but I would use a more literal word for "awakened", and also change the phrasing: *nullus* means "not any one", like German *keine*, while *nōn* means "not", like German *nicht*. So:

> *Nullus deus suscitātō praeest.*
>   No god stands higher than one who is awakened.

Answer (score 0):

For god ***'Dis',*** includes the ancient gods as well as the Olympian gods.

***Dis, ditis***  ([Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DD%3Aentry%20group%3D38%3Aentry%3DDis2)) 'god,' collectively 'the gods.'

For "is above," *[supersum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supersum)* is not the best word; it can mean: be superfluous, extra. It might be better to try *Praesum, -esse, praefui,* to be above, to be superior to, ([Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DP%3Aentry%20group%3D96%3Aentry%3Dpraesum)) followed by the *Dative.* "is not  above" ***non praeest.***

In classical Latin *illuminatus* describes 'brilliant' rhetoric and 'illustrious' wisdom. But by 1700, the *illuminati* was the name for  advanced students of various Gnostic philosophies. In the *Dative,* ***Illuminatis***

If you want to dissociate yourself from Gnosticism, *Prae-stans: (praestantior, praestantissimi)* [(L&S)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DP%3Aentry%20group%3D95%3Aentry%3Dpraesto2)

> A. In gen. (class.).
>   1. Of persons: *“omnibus praestans et ingenio et diligentiā,”* far surpassing all, Cic. Tusc. 1, 10, 22: *“usu et sapientiā praestantes,”* noted for their experience and wisdom, Nep. Timoth. 3,

In Dative *"in usu et sapientia praestantibus"* or shorter, *"in sapentia praestantibus."*

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard _Dīs_ meaning any deity except the lord of the underworld, and L&S seem to back me up on that (in Classical usage at least).